# When is convergence of uniformly bounded monotonically increasing functions uniform?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of monotonically increasing (ie. nondecreasing) functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$ with $0\leq f_n\leq 1$ for all $n$. In addition, $f_n\to f$ pointwise for some continuous $f$.

Baby Rudin (Principles of Mathematical Analysis 3rd Ed.) 7.13.b asks us to prove that the convergence must be uniform, but I think I have a counterexample: put $I(x)=0$ on $x<0$, $I(x)=1$ on $x\geq0$ and $f_n(x)=I(x-n)$ so that $f_n\to0$ pointwise but not uniformly.

Under what extra conditions is the original statement true? For example, require that the bounds $0\leq f\leq1$ be tight.

**Edit:** clarified definition of monotonic (this is the definition that Rudin uses).

Comment: Your functions $f_n$ are not monotonic.

Comment: @JacobSchlather: they are perhaps not strictly monotonic, but it wouldn't take much tweaking to make them so, and still satisfy the conditions.

Comment: @JacobSchlather: for example, use suitably scaled and translated versions of $I=\arctan$ or $I(x)=x/\sqrt(x^2+1)$. This shows that it is not sufficient to simply replace monotonic with strictly monotonic.

Comment: In the first edition, the problem is to show uniform convergence on compact sets.